# AWS ECS Fargate Service TargetTracking CPU based auto scaling generate Cloudwatch alarm for Low CPU Utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

I have ECC Fargate Service running with autoscaling (Targate Tracking CPU)

Why do I see the CloudWatch alarm in the "in alarm" state always for Low CPU utilization?
[image]

Is this because Target is set to 70% & these auto-scaling alarms trigger for both (low < 70 < up)?

I do not want this alarm against Low CPU in the "in alarm" state

Below is the Could Formation Code

```
#Policy type: Target Tracking scaling
#Disable scale-in: No



### ECS Service Target Tracking Auto Scaling Configuration
  ECSScalableTarget:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Condition: SetTargetTrackingAutoScaling
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 1
      MinCapacity: 1
      ResourceId: "serviceName"
      RoleARN: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/ecs.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_ECSService' 
      ScalableDimension: 'ecs:service:DesiredCount'  ## 1 The initial desired count to start with before Service Auto Scaling begins adjustment.
      ServiceNamespace: ecs

  ServiceScalingPolicyCPU:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Condition: SetTargetTrackingAutoScalingCPU
    Properties:
      PolicyName: target-tracking-cpu
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref ECSScalableTarget
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization
        TargetValue: 70
        ScaleInCooldown: 180
        ScaleOutCooldown: 60
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS AutoScaling will create a CloudWatch alarm to trigger a scale-up, and another alarm to trigger a scale-down. One of those will always be in the alarm state. It's just how the AutoScaling service works, and is not an issue. This is why there is a checkbox in the CloudWatch UI to hide AutoScaling alarms.